# Some <a> links just stopped working on my site

Tags: html, wordpress, hyperlink, anchor

I've ran into some weird problem that didn't exist before. The code is perfect, and all links are defined with `<a href="http://somesite.com">LINK</a>`. However, many links won't work when on an article post - on the homepage, all links works fine, as far as I can tell.

Here's a link to an article - try clicking on the four top links, for example: http://dedanseglade.no/2014/dd-anmelder-video-ingemars-de-saliges-kvarter/

This has been a problem on all the PC's we tested (and with different, modern web browsers), and it worked before with the same code. Suddenly, some links work, but some don't. I've never experienced anything like this before, and I'm quite experienced with HTML. I'm using the latest version of Wordpress, 3.9.

Comment: "Debug my web site" questions with only a link to the site are likely to be closed. To avoid it, you should create a minimal but complete example that shows the problem and paste the code in the question. See also [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Do you have onclick handlers for links set?

Comment: @Juhana I'm sorry, but this is a thing I can't reproduce. On every other website, this code works.

Comment: @Juhana OP is right about not replicating the problem in a JS fiddle or something similar. If replicated, it'll just work fine. This looks like there's some js, which is messing things up. I agree with @fjc, about `onclick` handlers being somewhere. I saw a clicktracker js(`jquery.clicktracker.js`), try removing that and test please.

Comment: please check this script: http://dansas.no/lightbox.js?ver=3.9 i think that problem is there. 'nav a' links have preventDefault() method applied to them... On home page - another script is used (cycle).

Comment: @xFortyFourx: then that probably means that the OP is completely unable to isolate the problem. As indicated in the [meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), the OP should have isolated the issue before asking a question. This will probably help no one in the future, seeing it is only an issue with a specific website ("**too localized**"), and that website might even go down.

Comment: @LéoLam, well.. this will help to man who asked question, right? :) And, yes, sometimes is impossible (or insufficient) to isolate problem, or to make jsfiddle. Without link to site, in this case - nobody could solve problem, i am sure.

Comment: @nevermind, thank you so much for your help. Everything works perfectly when changing the jQuery selector. And sorry for not posting in terms of the rules, but I was desperate and didn't know what to do, since the HTML code was correct.

Comment: @nevermind: the problem is that it just seems like the OP hasn't done any effort to find the reason (*note: I may be wrong, but that's how it appears to me*). If the issue couldn't be isolated, then why were we able to find the issue? Because *we* isolated the issue. We *debugged* for him. This is, as the OP himself states, against the site's policy. By the way, this question is now useless to future readers, as the issue has been fixed. It is **no longer reproductible**, and **too localized**.

Comment: @LéoLam - I did make an effort trying to find the issue - but when this is a site with many thousand readers every day, and some links doesn't work as expected, it was urgent, as this has been an issue for at least a week. I'm not too experienced with jQuery and JavaScript, and it would take me ages to find the problem. In the accepted answer, future readers could find out why their links doesn't work, too, if they have a preventDefault code like that themselves, so I think the question is partly helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your lightbox.js you've got this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'nav a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //some other code here
});
```

The links that are not working have been disabled by this lighbox.js so you need to either change the selector in your js file or change the `nav` element to a `div` element but this is just a workaround and I don't recommend it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything worked perfectly again when I just changed it to `'#lightbox nav a'`. Sloppy of me - should have thought about that.